# Connet API using react native

Tags: api, react-native

I have a problem with my API. I want to know the code structure for my react native, because i have problem to convert data with this value
[image]

T have tried using this code:

```
var data = {
                liveness:1,
                hp: '085156426760',
                email: 'stepheen.jonathaan@gmail.com',
                nama_lengkap: 'Stephen Jonathan Gustav',
                jumlah: 1500000,
                komentar: 'test',
                hubungan_dengan_peminjam: 'orangtua',
                jangka_waktu: '15 hari',
                id_warung: '123ab',
                nama_pt: 'dbi'
}
```

here's the photo 
[image]

Comment: Add more clear information about your question.. Did you want to know how to make API Requests and Get API Responses ?

Comment: yes please @AkilaDevinda

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile apps need to load resources from a remote URL. You may want to make a POST request to a **REST API**, or you may need to fetch a chunk of static content from another server.

React Native provides the **Fetch API** for your networking needs. Fetch will seem familiar if you have used **XMLHttpRequest** or other networking APIs before.

**Making requests**

In order to fetch content from an arbitrary URL, you can pass the URL to fetch:

```
fetch('Your URL to fetch data from');
```

Fetch also takes an optional second argument that allows you to customize the HTTP request. You may want to specify additional headers, or make a **POST** request:

```
fetch("Your URL to fetch data from", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: "yourValue",
    secondParam: "yourOtherValue"
  })
});
```

Networking is an inherently asynchronous operation. Fetch methods will return a **Promise** that makes it straightforward to write code that works in an asynchronous manner:

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  return fetch("Your URL to fetch data from")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

You can also use the proposed **ES2017 async/await** syntax in a React Native app:

```
async function getMoviesFromApi() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch("Your URL to fetch data from");
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJSon);
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Another method to API Call is [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Axios is a hugely popular (over 52k stars on Github) HTTP client that allows us to make GET and POST requests from the browser.

**Example Full Codebase**

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }



  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

For more information about Networking - [View](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)

Answer (score 0):

Axious is promise based http client for browser and nodejs.Axious makes it easy to send asynchronous HTTP requests to REST endpoints and perform CRUD operations.

```
   const data = new FormData();

     data.append("foto_selfie_kttp", {
      uri: response.uri,
      type: response.type,
      name: response.fileName});

     data.append("foto_ktp", {
      uri: response.uri,
      type: response.type,
      name: response.fileName});

     data.append(
      "inputString",
      JSON.stringify({
       {
            liveness:1,
            hp: '085156426760',
            email: 'stepheen.jonathaan@gmail.com',
            nama_lengkap: 'Stephen Jonathan Gustav',
            jumlah: 1500000,
            komentar: 'test',
            hubungan_dengan_peminjam: 'orangtua',
            jangka_waktu: '15 hari',
            id_warung: '123ab',
            nama_pt: 'dbi'
        }
      })
    );

   const URL = FILE_UPLOAD_URL;
    return axios(URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: "Basic shyhbG9tOnNoYWxvsadAMTIz"
      },
      data: data
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.success === true) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
      });
```